# InfoPath People Picker not posting back on Edit

Tags: 2010, infopath, people-picker

I have an InfoPath that I set a People Picker field via a rule when the value of a drop down changes. This works when creating a new item but does not work on Edit Item. It appears to be that the People Picker does not postback like the controls do and it does not have the postback settings like other controls. Does anyone know how to force a People Picker to postback?

**Date Picker Postback Settings**

[image: Date Picker Postback Settings]

**People Picker Settings**

[image: People Picker Settings]

Comment: I don't know if this will matter, but is this an InfoPath form for a library or a list?

Comment: It is a list...